# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. String to MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

```
var currentPageMenu = "menu" + currentPageSingle.toUpperCase() + currentPageLast;
leftMenu.currentPageMenu.addChild(menuLineImg);
```

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>
> at index_fla::MainTimeline/pageContainerSky()

I think `currentPageMenu` fails because the string.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var currentPageMenu = "menu" + currentPageSingle.toUpperCase() + currentPageLast;
leftMenu[currentPageMenu].addChild(menuLineImg);
```